# notepad++ how to insert replacement after the following word

Tags: replace, notepad++, boundary

```
text: [aa-b c d...]
result: [b-123 c d...]

text:[aa-word1 word2 word3 ...]
result[word1-123 word2 word...]

[aa-bananas oranges apples]
[bananas-123 oranges apples]
```

I want to replace `aa-` but `-123` should be only placed after the next word.
The next word should be a parameter, instead of a fixed text like the insert `aa-`. This is because there are many different cases to be replaced.

I'll change "aa-" to many other variants. "bb-" "cc-"...
But the word1 is always a variable in the text.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid I don't follow your example. I'm also worried that an example won't be general enough for you use case when you say "there are many more cases to be replaced". Can you please clarify exactly what you're asking? 4-5 examples would be awesome (or enough to cover any potential edge cases).

Comment: text:[aa-word1 word2 word3 ...]
    result[word1-aa word2 word...]
    
    [aa-bananas oranges apples]
    [bananas-aa oranges apples]

I'll change "aa-" to many other variants. "bb-" "cc-"...
But the word1 is always a variable in the text.

Comment: Please edit the post to include this info and thanks. Basically, you're swapping the  words that are hyphenated? What's the rule here exactly?

Comment: Basically, yes. But what I need to know is how to transport the replacement only after the next following word, which can't be changed.

Comment: I still don't really follow what you're asking. How do I identify the first word that should be replaced? Can you post like 10-15 lines of text? Are the brackets part of the string? Is the dash part of the string? It looks to me like you want to find a hyphenated word, move the second word to the first, and replace the first word with 123? It looks like you want `\w+\-(\w+)`, replace with `$1-123`, but I can't be sure.

Comment: That's it. But how can I make the "\w+\-(\w+)" fit 'aa-'? And only that.

Comment: Try something like `aa\-(\w+)`?

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\[aa-(\w+)`
- Replace with: `[$1-123`
- *check Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\[          # opening square bracket
aa          # literally 2 a
-           # hyphen
(\w+)       # group 1, 1 or more word character
```

**Result for given example:**

```
[b-123 c d...]
[word1-123 word2 word3 ...]
[bananas-123 oranges apples]
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]